# Best Way to Switch a Bit in an Integer?

Tags: binary, integer, boolean-logic

Say I want to switch the 5th bit in a **32-bit** / 64-bit integer (zero based, bit-index = 4). What's the most performant way to do that ?

Example in byte length: **01001010** → **01011010**

Languages of interest are:

- Actionscript 3
- C#
- Java:

  - `int x = y ^ (1 << n);` hint by [redcayuga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199838/redcayuga)
- C/C++

Answer (score 0):

You want to EXCLUSIVE OR a 1. In java:

```
x = y ^ ( 1 << (n-1))
```

I'm counting the bits from right to left, i.e. from the least significant bit. I start at zero.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I count the bits the same way. But `n = 0` for the first bit already.